# Prevent the button click again once the dropdown menu has opened from the button React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, togglebutton

I'm trying to stop the button from clicking again once the dropdown menu is enabled from when the button gets clicked.
button clicks -> opens dropdown. the only way the menu can close is from an outside click, and not from the button, that is from the useOnClickOutside "usehooks-ts". The button should only be able to click and open the menu if the menu is closed. thanks in advance if anyone can help with the problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-wilson-4wbj0?file=/src/App.js
(here is the sandbox, but the tailwindcss npm is not working on it.)

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useOnClickOutside } from "usehooks-ts";

export const DropDownMenu = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setShowMenu(!showMenu);

  const handleClickOutside = () => setShowMenu(false);

  useOnClickOutside(ref, handleClickOutside);

  return (
    <div className="mt-20">
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="bg-yellow-300 ml-5 text-sm2 
        border-solid border-2 border-blue-300"
      >
        <div>Open Menu</div>
      </button>
      <div
        ref={ref}
        className={`absolute top-8  w-240 opacity-0 bg-red-200 ml-20 
          ${showMenu ? "opacity-100 visible" : ""}`}
      >
        <ul>
          <li className="">Menu Item One</li>
          <li className="">Menu Item Two</li>
          <li className="">Menu Item Three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropDownMenu;
```

Comment: I added  disabled={showMenu} into the button and it prevents the button from being clicked once the menu is open, only issue is that if i want to add text and an icon to the button It still gets clicked

Comment: I solved it buy adding       ```<div ref={ref} className="flex justify-center items-center relative mt-20">```  just under the return and ```disabled={showMenu}``` in the button, this took me many days to work out ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add condition in handleClick, to check if showMenu is false and then proceed:

```
const handleClick = () => !showMenu && setShowMenu(!showMenu);
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a correct answer, but its conflicting with the outside click.

Answer (score 0):

Stop overthinking things. Simply place the ref on the parent component of the button and dropdown, so that it does not detect the child components :)

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useOnClickOutside } from "usehooks-ts";

export const DropDownMenu = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setShowMenu(!showMenu);

  const handleClickOutside = () => setShowMenu(false);

  useOnClickOutside(ref, handleClickOutside);

  return (
    <div className="mt-20" ref={ref}> // Place ref here
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="bg-yellow-300 ml-5 text-sm2 
        border-solid border-2 border-blue-300"
      >
        <div>Open Menu</div>
      </button>
      <div
        className={`absolute top-8  w-240 opacity-0 bg-red-200 ml-20 
          ${showMenu ? "opacity-100 visible" : ""}`}
      >
        <ul>
          <li className="">Menu Item One</li>
          <li className="">Menu Item Two</li>
          <li className="">Menu Item Three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropDownMenu;
```